# Helm, by default, does not manage or modify custom resources like WorkflowTemplates?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argo, argo-events

We have created two argoevents helm charts apart from argoworkflow chart.

1. argoeventsCRD
2. argoeventsObj

argoeventsCRD contains the CRD's and argoeventsObj contains the argoworkflow templates

Now after helm install everything works fine but when we are helm upgrading argoworkflow chart with updated chart version of argoeventsCRD and argoeventsObj charts (updated one image for container in one of the WorkflowTemplate).

We do not see changes reflected in WorkflowTemplate in argo UI.

Does helm upgrade  do not support updating custom resources but just the kubernetes native objects(deployments, services, and config maps).

Comment: Issue is resolved WorkflowTemplate were deployed as helm hooks(post-install). To update them on chart upgrade just updated the helm hook to post-upgrade